# How to get JavaScript to press a series of keys in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, key

I want to make a JavaScript program that will allow my a simulator of pressing the left and right arrow keys. For example, IF I press the "up" arrow key, I would like for this to press the left arrow key 3 times, then the right arrow key 3 times. I want this to be in an infinitely long loop, until I press the "down" arrow key. I'm VERY new with JavaScript, and I was hoping somebody could please help me!

Comment: I assume you're doing this in a Web browser? you can fire `keypress` events with JavaScript. You need to specify the event's target (can be the whole page or a specific UI element like a text field). Those events will be marked by the browser as "fake" events, prevented from doing certain sensitive things like click a button that triggers audio playback or file upload. In any case, the keystrokes will only affect the webpage. Is that compatible with your intent?

Comment: Do you really need to simulate key presses or does it suffice if you just fire the same events that the very key presses would fire?